# google spreadsheet editor: update sparse cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to update roughly 300 sparse cells, like A1, B200, A1000, B5000, A6000, A6001... in a spreadsheet with about 10000 rows, and 200 columns.

Right now I am updating cells one by one, but I was looking for batch method to make just 1 call and pass an array to update only these cells. I searched other SO threads and google spreadsheet documentation, but for batch updates they are mostly for consecutive cells in a range. I couldn't find anything for updating sparse cells with one call.

Google recommendation is to make batch updates instead of individual calls. So is there any method to make a call and pass only the cells that need to be updated?

Comment: How do you determine which cells to update?  Meaning, what is your definition of a sparse cell?

Comment: @Karl_S the spreadsheet is updated daily, and the cells needing update are determined from the other columns in their rows. A simplified example would be like this: Col C, D determines whether A, B needs to be updated. So they are not predetermined.

Comment: OK, so sparse just means various unconnected cells in the file.  What factors would determine which cells would be changed?  If Col D is _____ then B becomes _____, or something similar to this would be what I am looking to know. Can you provide a sample file?  Also, is the file updated daily via a formula, script, or manually?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) with [Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) & `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId)`

Be sure to **[Enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the service in your script**

```
function updateMultipleRanges () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range_one = sheet.getRange("A1:D3").getA1Notation();
  var range_two = sheet.getRange("G1:G4").getA1Notation();
  
  // Create the JSON Request Body
  var update_req = {
    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
    "data": [{
        "range": range_one,
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]],
      },
      {
        "range": range_two,
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
      }],
    "includeValuesInResponse": false
  }

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(JSON.stringify(update_req), ss.getId())
}
```

Create a [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) object for each range you want to update and add it to the `data[]`

Comment: This is a great answer. But still I need to make calls to get range which has the same linear complexity as calling updateCell for each cell update.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do? You said `I was looking for batch method to make just 1 call and pass an array to update only these cells` - This sounds like you have the ranges you want to update, but just needed to know how you could do it in one call. The `array` of cells to update should be passed into  `update_req.data` in the above JSON example - they just have to be formatted into [ValueRange's](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange)